# React js, confuses fetch url with another fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

In my Home component, I have this fetch function

```js
export default function Home() {
  const { rootUrl } = useContext(UserContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${rootUrl}/api/products/featuredProducts`)
      .then((result) => result.json())
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      });
  }, []);
}
```

That is supposed to pull products from the db which are featured.
But every time I try to run that fetch it confuses with another fetch in my app which is the get single product fetch, which is this code:

```js
export default function ProductView() {
  const { productId } = useParams();
  const { rootUrl } = useContext(UserContext);
  const { addToCart } = useContext(UserContext);
  const [productData, setProductData] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${rootUrl}/api/products/${productId}`)
      .then((result) => result.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setProductData(result);
      });
  }, []);
```

I will get an error in my backend API with this message:

```
 CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "featuredProducts"
```

That "featuresProducts" is my endpoint for my first fetch. It seems that something is confusing it as my parameter ID for my second fetch url in my ProductView component, this fetch below:

```
fetch(`${rootUrl}/api/products/${productId}`)
```

I don't understand why is this happening as my other routes with "api/products/plus other endpoints here" work just fine, it's just this my new addition to fetch featured products won't work

Comment: How do you define your routes server-side?  If you have a route looking for `/api/products/<some_value>` then I would expect a request to `/api/products/featuredProducts` to match that route with "featuredProducts" as the value.  It sounds like you've mis-configured your route definitions, not that "react is confusing one URL with another".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined your route as `/products/:id`, so whenever your backend sees a route like `/products/anything` it will automatically (and correctly) assume the `anything` is id. You can combat this in various ways.

What I would do is, create one route for fetching with id:

```
/products/id/:id
```

and another for featured:

```
/products/featured
```

in your backend.